# Android: Adding XML config file?

Tags: android, xml, config

How can I add a `XML Config` file to my Android project, as described at this link (step 1):

http://java.dzone.com/articles/working-google-analytics-api

Is it the same as an ordinary `XML` file?

Comment: OMG, just some source code beautifier f**up the xml ... download the source and check how it is done

Comment: are referring to step 3 in the link? what is not clear about it?

Comment: I am not able to see where to download the source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the file in `/res/xml` folder

Answer (score 2):

Create an 'xml' folder inside your 'res' folder. Put the xml file inside the xml folder.